# What's wrong with XPath testing on codebeautify.org?

Tags: xml, xpath

For the example XML:

```
<aaa name ="a1">
  <bbb name="b1"/>
  <bbb name="b2"/>
  <ccc name="c1">
    <bbb name="b3"/>
  </ccc>
  <ddd name="d1">
    <bbb name="b4"/>
  </ddd>
</aaa>
```

I would like to select all `bbb` nodes whose parents are not `ccc` nodes. This would be the nodes with name `b1`, `b2` and `b4`.

I have tried the XPath `/aaa//bbb[not(parent::ccc)]`, but this still selects all of the `bbb` nodes at https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CodeBeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester.) is wrong, and your XPath is correct.**

Your XPath should select

```
<bbb name="b1"/>
<bbb name="b2"/>
<bbb name="b4"/>
```

meeting your expectations that no `<bbb name="b3"/>`) be selected.

Given such a basic problem, I would avoid CodeBeautify.

Here are two alternative online XPath sites that return the correct result:

- **XPath 1.0:** http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath
- **XPath 2.0+:** http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Comment: At least on an online xpath tester, this doesn't seem to work. It still selects all bbb nodes

Comment: Above is correct.  Got a link to demonstrate otherwise?

Comment: Confirmed.  **That site is wrong.  Avoid.**  No wonder you were confused.  Your XPath and your understand are correct.   Here are two sites that are more reliable for online XPath testing:  XPath 1.0:  http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath; XPath 2.0+: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using the xpath

```
/aaa//bbb[local-name(..) != 'ccc']
```

Comment: Is your actual XML using namespaces that you're not showing in your posted XML?

Comment: The above technique is used to disregard namespaces.  It is not necessary for your XML, which is not in a namespace.  It's also not recommended for XML that *is* in a namespace.   I've confirmed that [the site you were using](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) fails for your XPath `/aaa//bbb[not(parent::ccc)]` against your XML.   Such a result is ***wrong***.  You should avoid that site.